# C++ variable value saved after recalling function

Tags: c++

I don't understand the behaviour of the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

bool playGame() {

    //game procedure here

    cout<<"Would you like to play again (y or n)? ";

    char choice;    //the problem here <<------
    while(!(choice == 'n' || choice == 'y')) {
        cin>>choice;
    }

    if(choice == 'y')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main() {
    bool play = true;

    while(play){
        play = playGame();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Suppose i enter 'y' for the variable choice the first time the playGame() is called. This value will be saved for the consecutive calls of playGame() in the variable choice, and while loop will not get executed. Why is that?

Comment: Seems you are reading `choice` before you read a value into it the first time...

Comment: Use a `do-while` loop instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior since you are using `choice` before initializing it.

We can try to explain the behavior but that's pointless when you are looking at undefined behavior.

Initialize `choice` to a sensible value and your program will be well behaved.

```
char choice = {};  // Initializes choice to zero.
while(!(choice == 'n' || choice == 'y')) {
    cin>>choice;
}
```

---

I would write the code to check whether the input is valid a bit differently though, using a helper function.

```
bool isValidInput(char choice)
{
    return (choice == 'n' || choice == 'y');
}

...


char choice = {};  // Initializes choice to zero.
while( !isValidInput(choice) ) {
    cin>>choice;
}
```

Comment: (A + B)! = A!B!

Comment: @ArdentCoder, please elaborate.

Comment: Just the De Morgan's law. I thought that was more readable, just a matter of taste :P

Comment: @ArdentCoder, I understand that. Do you think the code should be changed because of that? If not, what's the point of the comment?

Comment: It's just a comment, not an accusation. It may also help someone who likes the other way of writing that condition.

Comment: Relax, one of the upvotes is mine. I agree with your answer.

Comment: @ArdentCoder, no problem. I just wanted to understand the purpose of your comment. Thanks for the upvote.